# How do I return a view when progress is changed when using Backgroundworker on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, view, backgroundworker

I am updating values in a model using do work and then trying to return the view with the new values from the controller where i am using a background worker. I am aware i need to do this in progress changed however, as i am using backgroundworker on .NET MVC, im not sure if i am able to return the view as shown below:

```
private void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            nfcSer = new MainWindow();
            while (!e.Cancel)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                for (int i = 0; i < 50;)
                {
                    if (nfcSer.connectCard())
                    {

                        //this updates the student's attendance status to true
                        StudentsController.setAttendStudent(nfcSer.getcardUID(), Convert.ToInt32(Session["courseID"]));
                        i++;
                        _worker.ReportProgress(i);

                    }
                }
            }
```

```
        private void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //trying to return same view?
            return View("PortalStudents");
        }
```

Expected result: once the attended value of student is updated in db on do work, progress should be changed and same view should be called again with now attended set to true for that student.

Comment: How is the view handled otherwise? You can't return anything from the handler, but you can probably do it otherwise. What framework are you using for the views etc?

Comment: Im using MVC structure and .net framework

Comment: MVC is a way of doing things, but which library are you using for it? .NET doesn't have MVC built in for anything else than ASP.NET. So is this a web application? Or what is `View`?

Comment: Sorry, I am using ASP.NET Core web application which uses .net framework